# Repeatedly merging Pandas dataframe in python loses most data after the 3 merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am doing a set of merging on two dataframes. One data frame contains a two columns which shows which a parent child connection. Like this

| RID | Child_RID |
| --- | --- |
| xxxxx | yyyyy |
| yyyyy | zzzzz |

Where a child will appear in the RID section to as they may also have children

I have a second dataframe that has more information on an object like this

| name | RID | Child_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| site | xxxx | yyyy |
| site | xxxx | oooo |
| somthing | iiii | llll |

I wrote a merging function to reuse as i will keep doing it for a number of times until there are no children left.

And for the first merge it works fine and produces what I want. But on the second and third merge it drops information. I would expect for it to have nan if there is missing data which is what I want. but it erases pretty much parts or all the of previous merges.

```
def merge_dataset(df1, list_df, index_1, index_2):
    num_df = pd.DataFrame(list_df, columns = [index_1,index_2])
    df2 = pd.merge(df1, num_df, on=index_1)
    return df2
```

And this is how I use this method

```
mg1 = merge_dataset(df, parent_child_longlist, 'child_1','child_2')
# Change column order
cols = ['name', 'rid', 'child_1','child_2']
mg1 = mg1[cols]
```

And this works fine producing this
[image: First Merge]

The second merge seemed to drop information from the dataframe which I dont know why. I would expect for it to have more rows than the first merge
[image: Merge 2]
I called the second merge like the first one

```
mg2 = merge_dataset(mg1, parent_child_longlist, 'child_2','child_3')
cols = ['name', 'rid', 'child_1','child_2', 'child_3']
mg2 = mg2[cols]
```

The issue is magnified with the third merge. I call it the same way

```
mg3 = merge_dataset(mg2, parent_child_longlist, 'child_3','child_4')
cols = ['name', 'rid', 'child_1','child_2', 'child_3', 'child_4']
mg3 = mg3[cols]
```

But then drops 90% of the data like this
[image: Merge 3]

So I am a bit lost as to why it would drop all the data after this third merge when the first two seems to work just fine. And i will need to do this 10 or 20 more times until all the parent child connections are mapped in this dataframe.

Comment: maybe try with the parameter `how='left'` or `'outer'` in the merge because by default, it does a `'inner'` merge :)

Comment: dude you are god sent. I tried outer and left before but it failed on me and I got back to basics this round. Setting how to outer fixed the issue and did it perfect. Could you post that as the answer and I will accept

Comment: I will more flag as dup to redirect towards pandas merge 101 and leave the comment to help future readers :)